# Web scraping with R: web site has two drop down menus

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to get grade data from the following web site using `R`'s for loop function: https://www7.nau.edu/pair/reports/ClassDistribution

In order to get the table data I have to first choose year and then academic school. I need data for 2015-2019 and for all schools (ACC, ACM,...,WGS) within university. When I select year and school the url is not changing that is why I am getting no table data. I'd really appreciate your help and advice. I am able to create for loop, I just need to see how to pull first table.

I was using following code for a static web site:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url <- "https://www7.nau.edu/pair/reports/ClassDistribution"
url.parsed <- htmlParse(getURL(url), asText = TRUE)
tableNodes <- getNodeSet(url.parsed, '//*[@id="pp_table"]/table')
grade_data <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[1]], header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dealing with a simple form that you need to update and submit for each semester and subject. Selenium is fine, but I think it might be overkill here. `rvest::html_session` is good at this kind of thing:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# Start session, extract semesters from form and filter.
session <- html_session("https://www7.nau.edu/pair/reports/ClassDistribution")
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
semesters <- form$fields[[5]]$options[-1]
semesters <- semesters[grep("201[5-9]", names(semesters))]

# Update form with semester info, submit, and extract subjects.
form <- set_values(form, 'ctl00$MainContent$TermList' = semesters[1])
session <- submit_form(session, form, "<unnamed>")
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
subjects <- form$fields[[6]]$options

# Update form with subject, submit, and extract data frame(s).
form <- set_values(form, 'ctl00$MainContent$SubjectList' = subjects[1])
session <- submit_form(session, form, "ctl00$MainContent$Button1")

df_list <- html_table(session, T, T, T)
```

Two things to be aware of:

1. `df_list` returns a list of data frames that you'll need to combine. I recommend `dplyr::bind_rows()`.
2. You'll need two loops: An outer loop for the semesters, and an inner loop for the subjects within each semester.

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Comment: Both of these solutions worked for me and saved a lot of time!

Comment: @DominikS.Meier yeah, for some reason you don't see it that much. Probably because the idea of a "session" is a little daunting/confusing, and the function documentation isn't particularly thorough.

Comment: @BehzodA, no problem! Make sure you click the check mark to accept whichever answer helped you the most so others know what worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `RSelenium`.

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox")) #specify browser type you want Selenium to open
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("https://www7.nau.edu/pair/reports/ClassDistribution") # navigates to webpage


# select first dropdown list
option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="MainContent_TermList")

#get all option values from dropdown list
option_values <- option$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  str_extract_all("1[0-9]{3}")

#select second dropdown list
option2 <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="MainContent_SubjectList")

#get all option values from dropdown list
option_values_2 <- option2$getElementText() %>% 
  str_split("\\n") %>% 
  unlist()

#### create loop to loop over all tables...


option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="MainContent_TermList")

option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = '1194']") #change '1194' to values in option_values in loop
option$clickElement()

# change dropdown selection
option2 <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="MainContent_SubjectList")
option2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = 'AHB']") #change 'AHB' to values in option_values_2 in loop
option2$clickElement()

# click submit
submit <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="MainContent_Button1")
submit$clickElement()


#get table
tb <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="MainContent_GridView1")

tb$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Now you just have to loop over `option_values` and `option_values2` to get the tables.

Comment: Thank you Dominik for your help.